# Create docx word document web api .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, report, asp.net-core-2.0, dynamic-reports

I am developing a Web API project in Asp.net core 2.0. I am in need of a library or way to create Word document. I have searched an tried NPOI and DocX. Both are not as good as expected. Can anyone suggest me a tool?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

At first glance, the below link can help somehow:

https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2017/02/23/word-document-formatter-in-aspnetcore.html

Anyway, about DOCX - Word Document using Open XML SDK by Microsoft - you can install Open XML SDK into your solution using the version 2.8.1. It´s all free.

Documentation avaliable at:

On GIT => https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK ;

On MSDN => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk

ps: the MSDN documentation is all about the version SDK 2.5 instead of 2.8.1,  but as explained in the GIT link there is no substancial changes.

Anyway to use it in a Web APP CORE 2.0 you can do the follow:

1. INstall the Nuget Packgaes version SDK 2.8.1
2. Reference the below namespaces within your controller:

   ```
   using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
   using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
   using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
   ```
3. If you just want to save it in a folder locally do something like:

   ```
   public static void CreateWordprocessingDocument(string filepath)
   {
       // Create a document by supplying the filepath. 
       using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
           WordprocessingDocument.Create(filepath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
       {
           // Add a main document part. 
           MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

           // Create the document structure and add some text.
           mainPart.Document = new Document();
           Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
           Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
           Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
           run.AppendChild(new Text("Create text in body - CreateWordprocessingDocument"));
       }
   }
   ```

and call it like:

```
 public IActionResult GenerateDocx()
    {
        string filePath = @"c:\word\Invoice.docx";
        CreateWordprocessingDocument(filePath);
    }
```

4. If you want to generate a docx to be saved into a users computer from their browsers, after hitting a link, do something like:

   ```
   // GET verb
   public IActionResult GenerateDocxBrowser()
   {

       // open xml sdk - docx
       using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
       {
           using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
           {
               wordDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
               // siga a ordem
               Document doc = new Document();
               Body body = new Body();

               // 1 paragrafo
               Paragraph para = new Paragraph();

               ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
               ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Normal" };
               Justification justification1 = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Center };
               ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties1 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();

               paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);
               paragraphProperties1.Append(justification1);
               paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties1);

               Run run = new Run();
               RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();

               Text text = new Text() { Text = "The OpenXML SDK rocks!" };

               // siga a ordem 
               run.Append(runProperties1);
               run.Append(text);
               para.Append(paragraphProperties1);
               para.Append(run);

               // 2 paragrafo
               Paragraph para2 = new Paragraph();

               ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties2 = new ParagraphProperties();
               ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId2 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Normal" };
               Justification justification2 = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Start };
               ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties2 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();

               paragraphProperties2.Append(paragraphStyleId2);
               paragraphProperties2.Append(justification2);
               paragraphProperties2.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties2);

               Run run2 = new Run();
               RunProperties runProperties3 = new RunProperties();
               Text text2 = new Text();
               text2.Text = "Teste aqui";

               run2.AppendChild(new Break());
               run2.AppendChild(new Text("Hello"));
               run2.AppendChild(new Break());
               run2.AppendChild(new Text("world"));

               para2.Append(paragraphProperties2);
               para2.Append(run2);

               // todos os 2 paragrafos no main body
               body.Append(para);
               body.Append(para2);

               doc.Append(body);

               wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document = doc;

               wordDoc.Close();
           }
           return File(mem.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "ABC.docx");
       }

   }
   ```

the above code even shows how to use the most important objects: body, paragraphs, runs and text. Remember to follow this order always!

Comment: Is it possible to generate .docx file from html and css ? I want to create an web api application which that generate docx files, and another applications which need to generate docx, call my docx generator application . in other word I want to create an docx generator which another applications can get help from that. and only way which I find to commiunicate between my applications ,is use html and css strings to generate files . offcourse, if is possible another better way to do this job, please explains that for me.

Comment: When I utilize the above from a web api return like the example above I get. "Word found unreadable content in [filename].docx. Do you want to recover the contents of this document? If you trust the source, click Yes.". Any thoughts on why this would happen?